# How to drag a polygon in the same fashion as the dragging a point mapbox-gl-js example?

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I have a geojson polygon adding to the map with the click of a button. I also have the style of the polygon changing on the `mousedown` event on the geojson and the x/y coord pairs (the geojson geometry) printing to the console accessing it through the queryRenderedFeatures call on the API.

I am now wanting to make the polygon draggable like the point example (links below) on the `mousedown` event on the polygon and be able to move it on the map, updating the x/y coords of the polygon nodes throughout the `mousedown` event, but keeping the geojson size intact throughout the drag.

Is straight [mapbox-gl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) the way to do this, or should I be feeding a pre-configured geojson polygon into a [mapbox-gl-draw - draw polygon mode](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md#draw_polygon) on a user's action?

Any suggestions or examples?

[API Drag A Point Example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/)

[Drag A Point GitHub Code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/0ce209596c6654bc0016c6dd0d7761f88afcba33/docs/_posts/examples/3400-01-24-drag-a-point.html)

Comment: were you able to resolve this without mapbox draw?

Comment: Hi @Shawn have you found any solution we need to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   var isDragging = false;
var startCoords;

map.on('click', function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['polygon-layer'] });
  var polygon = features[0];
  if (!polygon) return;
  
  startCoords = polygon.geometry.coordinates[0];
});

map.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  isDragging = true;
});

map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  
  var coords = map.unproject(e.point);
  var delta = {
    lng: coords.lng - startCoords[0],
    lat: coords.lat - startCoords[1]
  };
  
  polygon.geometry.coordinates[0] = polygon.geometry.coordinates[0].map(function(coord) {
    return [coord[0] + delta.lng, coord[1] + delta.lat];
  });
  
  map.getSource('polygon-source').setData(polygon);
});

map.on('mouseup', function(e) {
  isDragging = false;
});
```

the polygon is being stored as a GeoJSON feature, and the polygon layer and source are named 'polygon-layer' and 'polygon-source', respectively. You will need to adjust these names to match your setup.